# what is the difference between a.out file and .elf file format

Tags: exe, elf, out

Can any one please tell me what is the difference between .out and .elf file?

either .elf file consist debug information or not?

And what is fully statically linked exe file?

Answer (score 2):

ELF (Executable and Linkable Format) is a binary format created for the UNIX operating system, but it is also used in many UNIX clones, including Linux. A.OUT format is also a binary format created for UNIX but also used in various UNIX clones. The differences between the formats are not something I shall go into, but if you wish, you can research it yourself. A.OUT is much older than ELF, and by which, much more limiting, so it isn't used as much today compared to ELF.

It is notable to mention as well that "a.out" is the default name of an executable that is generated by GCC, even though it is usually compiled to ELF by default.

ELF is not a version of A.OUT with debug symbols or something like that, but it is best to think of them as two different things that strive to do the same thing.

Answer (score -1):

The .out could be the binary that will be running in the Computer/board and the elf is the file that gives information about the binary. For example it may provide information at which adress of the binary each variable is located.

Comment: thank you for the replay,is .elf consist debug information?

Comment: elf contains information of what is stored at each position of the binary. This information can be used by debugging programs, for example, to translate the instruction that is currently being run into which line of code it is represented.

Comment: This isn't really true. ELF file is the format into which executable programs are stored for linux. a.out is simply the default filename output by gcc. If compiled on linux, a.out IS an elf file. It only has a different file extension. The content is still an executable elf.

Comment: My response is based on assumtions. It is not defined in the questions if he is compiling in linux, gcc or any other program.

Comment: Your answer is misleading

Comment: Linux, GCC, or any other program? GCC (by default) compiles for Linux, on Linux. Your answers should never be based off of assumptions.

Comment: I should mention as well, Asha, that as you advance in knowledge, you should take more time to do the research rather than asking questions, but I understand why you might've asked the question when you did